# Compare content of two different structs with same content

Tags: c++

I have two structures containing the same kind of content, but they are not the same.

```
struct ContainerType1 {
    uint8_t   isXYZ;
    uint32_t  foo;
    uint8_t   bar;
    uint32_t  nbOfItems;
    typeXX    ArryXXX[20]; };

struct ContainerType2 {
        uint8_t   isZ;
        uint32_t  x;
        uint8_t   y;
        uint8_t   z;
        uint32_t  nbOfItems;
        typeXX    ArryYY[20]; };
```

I want to compare objects for only selected elements of these structs.

```
bool CompareItems (ContainerType1  object1, ContainerType2  object2)
{
   if(object1.nbOfItems != object1.nbOfItems or object1.isXYZ != object1.isZ)
   {
       return false; 
   }

   for (int i=0; i< nbOfItems ; i++)
   {
        p1 = object1.ArryXXX;
        p2 = object2.ArryYY;

        if(p1.numberOfFoo != p2.numberOfBar)
           return false;
        if(p1.Foo.x != p2.Bar.x )
           return false;
        if(p1.a.y != p2.b.y )
           return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

****I don't have the ability to alter/ redesign these structs. I can only use them to compare.**

Is there a better way to do this? Like put everything I want to compare (ints and enums) in two arrays in the order and compare them?

Comment: A better way is to redesign all the classes, from scratch, and eliminate the unnecessary duplication, and simply let the usual `==` operator do all the work.

Comment: I find the code very muddled.  What is `typeXX`?

Comment: You should pass the parameters by constant reference, rather than having the compiler make copies.

Comment: "...Only the names have been changed to protect the innocent."  Change the member names so they are the same structure.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I cannot change/alter structs. I can only use them for comparison

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I cannot change the member names. I can only use the structs for comparison, not update them

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do so, as suggested by the comments under the question would be to use the == operator under one of the structs.

It would look something like this:

```
struct ContainerType1 {
    uint8_t   isXYZ;
    uint32_t  foo;
    uint8_t   bar;
    uint32_t  nbOfItems;
    typeXX    ArryXXX[20]; 
    
    bool operator == (const ContainerType2& other) const {
        // everything you want to compare in here
        // for example
        if (isXYZ != other.isZ) return false;
        // ...
    }
};

struct ContainerType2 {
    uint8_t   isZ;
    uint32_t  x;
    uint8_t   y;
    uint8_t   z;
    uint32_t  nbOfItems;
    typeXX    ArryYY[20]; 
};
```

Then to compare them you can simply do something like:

```
ContainerType1 a;
ContainerType2 b;
cout << (a == b) << endl;
```